# Editor unity3d not connect to services

Tags: unity-game-engine, unity-editor

My unity not anymore connecting to services.
Also can't connect to my server from unity request WWW, no one errors!

Asset store and package manager is work.

Watch video, for understanding.

https://gfycat.com/powerfulbewitchedhaddock

At the time of the problem the version was 2019.1.4, then i made update to 2019.1.7 and to last version and reinstall, without result!
 What could it be?

[img](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aNSaq.png)
Maybe something with membership? how is check?

Comment: Well it says your UnityID does not exist .. did you try to find out why?

Comment: @derHugo what is Unity ID and why did it suddenly cease to exist?
I’ve been using unity for three years and have never encountered this problem.

Comment: Me neither ;) I only know that the [Unity Project ID](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/SettingUpProjectServices.html) is required for using the services. Did you try to simply create a new one? Also make sure your ID is setup correctly [here](https://developer.cloud.unity3d.com/projects/)

Comment: Unity Project ID  created but not connected

Answer (score 1):

Solved!
It turns out the whole editor was not connected to the Internet.
In network preferences i disabled proxies/socks proxy and unity is live.
[img](https://i.stack.imgur.com/x4nQm.png)